# Как правильно передать конструктору строки

Tags: c++

Конструктор класса:

```
Play(char *m [15], char *f [15], bool a)
{
    name_male = &m;//name_male - поле класса
    name_female = &f;//name_female - поле класса
    a_enable = a;
}
```

И в `main`:

```
cin >> male;
cout << "Введите имя девочки: ";
cin >> female;
Play Game(male, female, 0);
Game.Menu();
```

Но пишется ошибка. Как правильно передать конструктору строки?

Answer (score 5):

Здесь всё неправильно. Используйте `std::string`.

```
std::string male,female;

Play(const std::string& m, const std::string& f, bool a)
{
   name_male = m;//name_male - поле класса
   name_female = f;//name_female - поле класса
   a_enable = a;
}
```

Comment: Очень правильный ответ. В C++ строка — это `std::string`, `char*` используется лишь для оптимизации и взаимодействия с внешним миром.

Comment: @VladD а почему char не стоит использовать?

Comment: @neko69: С точки зрения C++, `char*` слишком низкоуровневая штука, т. к. требует ручного управления памятью. Вам приходится думать, кто выделил его, кто должен скопировать, а кто может пользоваться как есть, и кто должен удалить. С `std::string` этих проблем нет.

Comment: @neko69: Ну и `std::string` проще и очевиднее в обращении. Например, чтобы сложить несколько строк типа `char*`, вам надо вручную подсчитать их размеры (`strlen`), выделить нужное количество памяти (`malloc`, не забудьте к сумме прибавить единицу!), скопировать все строки в получившийся буфер (`strcpy`), не забывая о том, куда должна попасть следующая строка. Для `std::string` это всего лишь `+`.

Comment: @neko69: С `std::string` вы теряете в эффективности, но выигрываете в простоте кода (а следовательно, надёжности).